# Array.prototype.filter() JavaScript modificar Array

Tags: javascript, filtro

tengo este codigo:

```js
const todos = []

const render = () => {
    const todoList = document.getElementById('items')
    const template = todos.map(x => '<li class="list-group-item">' + x + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">' + 'X' + '</button>' + '</li>')
    todoList.innerHTML = template.join('')
    const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#items li button')
    elementos.forEach((elemento, i) => {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
            elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento)
            todos.splice(i, 1)
            render()
        })
    })
    if (todos.length === 0) {
        const vacio = document.getElementById('items')
        vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>' + 'No hay tareas...' + '</h1>'
            //console.log(vacio)
    }
}

//filtro
filtro.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const items = document.getElementById('items')
    const texto = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    const datos = []
    if (texto === '') {
        render()
        //console.log('vacio');
    } else {
        //items.innerHTML = texto
        //console.log(texto);
        const filterItems = (query) => {
            return todos.filter((element) => element.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        }
        const template = filterItems(texto).map(x => '<li class="list-group-item">' + x + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">' + 'X' + '</button>' + '</li>')
        items.innerHTML = template.join('')
        const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#items li button')
        elementos.forEach((elemento, i) => {
            elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
                elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento)
                todos.splice(i, 1)
                render()
            })
        })
        //console.log(filterItems(texto));
    }

})

const form = document.getElementById('todo-form')
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todo = document.getElementById('todo')
    const todoText = todo.value
    todo.value = ''
    todos.push(todoText)
    render()

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Lista de Items</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="main-header" class="bg-info text-white p-4 mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 id="header-title">Lista de Items</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro" placeholder="Buscar item...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main" class="card card-body">
            <h2 class="title">Agregar Items</h2>
            <form id="todo-form" class="form-inline mb-3">
                <input id="todo" type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
            </form>
            <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
            <ul id="items" class="list-group">
                <h1>No hay tareas...</h1>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

tengo algunos problemas con el metodo para buscar una palabra en mi arreglo,
agrege el codigo html y la funcion donde uso filter,
puedo obtener los elementos y puedo eliminarlo, pero el problema es que si yo elimino un elemento con posicion digamos, 5 el metodo filter me va a eliminar siempre la posicion 0, lo que me di cuenta es que pasa porque en el nuevo arreglo los indices cambian, entonces mi idea es traer el elemento con su index del arreglo original, pero no se como hacerlo

muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No se entiende nada, no se dónde estás tratando de buscar algo en tu arreglo, ordena tu código, y sé más específico en qué parte del código tienes problemas.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el html?

Comment: La cosa es... aun no puedo encontrar donde dice que estas usando `filter` en tu codigo, solo veo `map` pero no encuentro filter, aparte veo que andas modificando mucho `HTML` en tus funciones, tu codigo puede no verse limpio haciendolo en todas las funciones, lo ideal si puedes es tener guardado el `HTML` como una constante al momento que se cargue el documento y pues en otra parte, de esa manera no tienes que estar haciendo todo el tiempo `document.getElementBy`... etc. y aparte se vera mas limpio.

Comment: ya he agregado el html con el codigo y mi funcion filter, gracias

Comment: pero funciona todo , que te falta?

Comment: al devolver el filtro no funciona el boton eliminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podes devolver un arreglo de objetos con `reduce` (con 2 propiedades), donde `element` es el elemento y el `indx` guarda el indice original , ese indice luego lo podes agregar a un `data-id` ( cuando barres con `map`) y cuando lo eliminas con el `splice` usas ese atributo para referencia el indice original
tambien te agregue la coincidencia del texto con `includes`

```
   const filterItems = (query) => {
    //usas el parametro opcional del indice para guardarlo como una clave en el objeto
     return       todos.reduce((acumulador,element,indx) =>{
        if(element.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())){
        acumulador.push({element,indx})
        
        }
        
        // console.log(acumulador)
    
        return acumulador
              
        },[] )
        
    }
```

```js
const todos = []

const render = () => {
    const todoList = document.getElementById('items')
    const template = todos.map(x => '<li class="list-group-item">' + x + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">' + 'X' + '</button>' + '</li>')
    todoList.innerHTML = template.join('')
    const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#items li button')
    elementos.forEach((elemento, i) => {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
            elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento)
            todos.splice(i, 1)
            render()
        })
    })
    if (todos.length === 0) {
        const vacio = document.getElementById('items')
        vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>' + 'No hay tareas...' + '</h1>'
            //console.log(vacio)
    }
}

//filtro
filtro.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const items = document.getElementById('items')
    const texto = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    const datos = []
    if (texto === '') {
        render()
        //console.log('vacio');
    } else {
        //items.innerHTML = texto
        //console.log(texto);
        const filterItems = (query) => {
         return       todos.reduce((acumulador,element,indx) =>{
            if(element.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())){
            acumulador.push({element,indx})
            
            }
            
            // console.log(acumulador)
        
            return acumulador
                  
            },[] )
            
        }
        const template = filterItems(texto).map(x => '<li data-id='+x.indx+ ' class="list-group-item">' + x['element'] + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">' + 'X' + '</button>' + '</li>')
       //console.log(template)
        items.innerHTML = template.join('')
        const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#items li button')
        elementos.forEach((elemento, i) => {
            elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let inx = elemento.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id')
                 
                elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento)
                todos.splice(inx, 1)
                render()
            })
        })
        //console.log(filterItems(texto));
    }

})

const form = document.getElementById('todo-form')
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todo = document.getElementById('todo')
    const todoText = todo.value
    todo.value = ''
    todos.push(todoText)
    render()

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Lista de Items</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="main-header" class="bg-info text-white p-4 mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 id="header-title">Lista de Items</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro" placeholder="Buscar item...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main" class="card card-body">
            <h2 class="title">Agregar Items</h2>
            <form id="todo-form" class="form-inline mb-3">
                <input id="todo" type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
            </form>
            <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
            <ul id="items" class="list-group">
                <h1>No hay tareas...</h1>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

### ALGUNAS REFERENCIAS

- [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
- [Atributo data](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos#:%7E:text=Los%20atributos%20data%2D*%20permiten,en%20el%20DOM%20o%20Node.)
- [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!